# findViewById of a view from the framelayout enclosing a fragment fails

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-framelayout

I have enclosed a fragment in a framelayout...and I am getting the child views of the fragment
using the framelayout.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pan);
    CardFragment fragment=new CardFragment();
    FragmentManager fm=getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.container, fragment);
    container=(FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);
    img_pan=(ImageView)container.findViewById(R.id.img_pan);
    txt_name=(TextView)container.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
    txt_father=(TextView)container.findViewById(R.id.txt_father);
    txt_dob=(TextView)container.findViewById(R.id.txt_dob);
    txt_type=(TextView)container.findViewById(R.id.txt_type);
    txt_panid=(TextView)container.findViewById(R.id.txt_panid);

}

@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    Intent i=getIntent();
    String name=i.getStringExtra("pan_name");
    String father=i.getStringExtra("pan_father");
    String dob=i.getStringExtra("pan_dob");
    String type=i.getStringExtra("pan_type");
    String panid=i.getStringExtra("pan_id");
    filePath=i.getStringExtra("pan_filePath");
    Log.d("CardActivity", "Filepath: "+filePath);
    Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
    if(bmp==null)
    {
        Log.d("CardActivity", "Error getting image to bitmap");
    }
    img_pan.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    txt_name.setText(name);
    txt_father.setText(father);
    txt_dob.setText(dob);
    txt_type.setText(type);
    txt_panid.setText(panid);
}
```

When I try to add values to the view,it throws a NullPointerException

EDIT:It was working just fine before I seperated everything into a Fragment..

**EDIT2:I have changed the Activity and the Fragment as suggested,the Activity onCreate:**

```
   Bundle state=new Bundle();
    state.putString("pan_name", name);
    state.putString("pan_father", father);
    state.putString("pan_dob", dob);
    state.putString("pan_type",type);
    state.putString("pan_id", panid);
    state.putString("pan_filepath", filePath);
    CardFragment fragment=new CardFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(state);
    FragmentManager fm=getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.container, fragment);
    ft.commit();
    if(fm.executePendingTransactions())
    {
        Log.d("CardActivity", "Executed all pending operations");
    }
```

**The fragment onCreateView method:**

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    img_pan=(ImageView)container.findViewById(R.id.img_pan);
    txt_name=(TextView)container.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
    txt_father=(TextView)container.findViewById(R.id.txt_father);
    txt_dob=(TextView)container.findViewById(R.id.txt_dob);
    txt_type=(TextView)container.findViewById(R.id.txt_type);
    txt_panid=(TextView)container.findViewById(R.id.txt_panid);
    Bundle bundle=getArguments();
    String name=bundle.getString("pan_name");//line 39
    String father=bundle.getString("pan_father");
    String dob=bundle.getString("pan_dob");
    String type=bundle.getString("pan_type");
    String id=bundle.getString("pan_id");
    String filePath=bundle.getString("pan_filepath");
    Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
    img_pan.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    txt_name.setText(name);
    txt_father.setText(father);
    txt_dob.setText(dob);
    txt_type.setText(type);
    txt_panid.setText(id);

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_pan, container,false);

}
```

Now it still returns a NullPointerException,the logcat seems to be pointed at the getArguments().I have tried using saveInstanceState without success.

```
     E/AndroidRuntime(13367): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
     E/AndroidRuntime(13367):   at     com.example.newscancardapp.CardFragment.onCreateView(CardFragment.java:39)
     E/AndroidRuntime(13367):   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1478)
     E/AndroidRuntime(13367):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
     E/AndroidRuntime(13367):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
     E/AndroidRuntime(13367):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1086)
     E/AndroidRuntime(13367):   at  android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1877)
     E/AndroidRuntime(13367):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:552)
     E/AndroidRuntime(13367):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1133)
     E/AndroidRuntime(13367):   at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:4529)
     E/AndroidRuntime(13367):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1929)
```

**Edit 3 This code is working:**

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View pan_layout=inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_card, container,false);
    img_pan=(ImageView)pan_layout.findViewById(R.id.img_pan);
    txt_name=(TextView)pan_layout.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
    txt_father=(TextView)pan_layout.findViewById(R.id.txt_father);
    txt_dob=(TextView)pan_layout.findViewById(R.id.txt_dob);
    txt_panid=(TextView)pan_layout.findViewById(R.id.txt_panid);
    Bundle bundle=getArguments();
    String name=bundle.getString("name");
    String father=bundle.getString("father");
    String dob=bundle.getString("dob");
    String id=bundle.getString("id");
    //String filePath=bundle.getString("filepath");
    //Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
    //img_pan.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    txt_name.setText(name);
    txt_father.setText(father);
    txt_dob.setText(dob);
    txt_panid.setText(id);
    return pan_layout;
}
```

Having refactored the code into a seperate app for testing...I have disabled the filePath.
Thanks to Luksprog for the answer.

Comment: It Will be Great if you post your LogCat also to Intrude in to your problem more visely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have enclosed a fragment in a framelayout...and I am getting the
>   child views of the fragment using the framelayout.

First of all, in order to actually bind the fragment to the activity you need to call the `commit()` method on your `FragmentTransaction`.

Even if you do this, your code will still fail because a fragment transaction is asynchronous, it doesn't happen when you call `commit()`, it will be scheduled in the future when the main UI thread finishes the current message. To solve this you could call `executePendingTransactions()` on the `FragmentManager` you use after committing(but this is not the proper route).

You shouldn't try to work with the views of the fragment directly. As you're trying to initialize the views of the fragment, this should be done either through passing a `Bundle` with the data as arguments to the fragment when you instantiate it or by making the fragment retrieve it directly from the activity(using `getActivity()` and casting it to your activity) in one of its callbacks(like `onCreateView()`).

Comment: added the changed files,this seems to be causing an error when retreiving the arguments...

Comment: @user2309862 Which one is line `39` in `CardFragment`? Also, in your `onCreateView()` method you should **first** inflate the `R.layout.layout_pan` layout, then look for the views in that inflated layout(and not in the container!). Also return the previously inflated view(and don't inflate it again).

Comment: String name=bundle.getString("pan_name"); is line 39.Should I use getArguments or savedInstanceState.

Comment: @user2309862 Your code is not sufficient to see what's the problem. Just for curiosity, put a log entry at the start of the `onCreateView` method and see how many times is called.

Comment: made the changes you suggested in the comment,the code seems to be working now...am posting the code of onCreateView with the changes.

Comment: @Luksprog am trying to open child fragment listview from parent fragment view on the same activity. child view should be on rif=ght side of parentview. i don't know how to achieve this. Can u help me